# What is the fastest way to filter list of tuples based on list of indices and values?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of sequences like: `seq = [(1,2,3,4) , (1,2,4,3) (1,3,2,4) (1,3,4,2)]`, etc..

And another list that contains tuples `(index , value)` of indexes and their corresponding values like so: `pos = [(3 , 4) , (1 , 2)]` (at index 3, there must be a 4. At index 1, there must be a 2).

How would i filter out the seq list in a way where i would remove all the tuples that **don't** have the values at their corresponding indexes in the `pos` list.
So for example, if I had the above seq and pos variables, the result would be:
`[(1,2,3,4)]`  because it is the only sequence that has a 2 in index one and 4 in index 3.

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work and is probably not the fastest way:

```
for i in range(len(seq)):
    for j in range(len(seq)):
        for x in range(len(pos)):
            if j == pos[x][0] and seq[i][j] == pos[x][1]:
                res.append(temp[i])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `all` function:

```py
seq = [(1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,3), (1,3,2,4), (1,3,4,2)]
pos = [(3, 4), (1, 2)]
filtered = [x for x in seq if all(x[i] == v for i, v in pos)]
print(filtered) # [(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` which may be faster if the data set is large enough to matter. This code creates an intermediate dataframe holding only the columns of interest, compared with their corresponding values. That dataframe is then used to select only the rows where *all* of the values are true.

```
import pandas as pd

seq = [(1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,3), (1,3,2,4), (1,3,4,2)]
pos = [(3 , 4) , (1 , 2)]

seq_df = pd.DataFrame(seq)
filter_df = seq_df[[i for i,_ in pos]] == [v for _,v in pos]
final_df = seq_df[filter_df.all(axis=1)]
```